# SQL UPDATE Confusion with linked tables (Subquery returned more than 1 value)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, sql-update

Database has a table A, and a table B. A.ID is linked with B.ID.

I need to update all instances of A.Name to be equal to B.Catalog, if and only if those instances are linked A.ID = B.ID.

Only entries in A where A.Owner = 0 should be updated.

The code I have come up with is:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Name = (SELECT B.Catalog
    FROM B, A
    WHERE (B.ID = A.ID) AND (A.Owner = 0))
WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT B.ID
    FROM B, A
    WHERE (B.ID = A.ID) AND (A.Owner = 0))
```

The error is `"Subquery returned more than one value"` (MS SQL 2005 adds `"MSG 512, LEVEL 16, STATE 1, LINE 1"`). I understand what the error is telling me, that I am trying to set a single value to be equal to the multiple results returned by the SELECT statement, but I think my knowledge of SQL is too lacking to come up with the proper code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I get for trying to teach myself! A headache!

Comment: Can there be more than 1 rows in table `B` with same `ID` but different `Catalog` ?

Comment: Problem solved, but just for clarification: nope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update A
set A.Name = B.Catalog
from TableA A
    join TableB B on
        A.Id = B.Id
where A.Owner = 0
```

Comment: @ShaneBlake & @Alex Aza
Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Name = B.Catalog
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Owner = 0
```